# How to access an array within a structure using only pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, struct, pointer-arithmetic

Is it possible to do the same thing as I did below, but without using `[]` or `->`.

I don't understand why `.*(points + 2)` doesn't work. Shouldn't this replace array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int points[2];
}_student;

int foo(_student *stud);

int main()
{
    int second;
    _student students[2];
    students[1].points[1] = 100;
    second = foo(students);

    printf("%d", second); 
    return 0;
}

int foo(_student *stud) // returns 3rd member of the array within a struct
{
    int second;
    second =  (*(stud+1)).points[1]; // Works
    //second =  (*(stud+1)).*(points+1);  ----> Does not work!

    return second;
}
```

The result should be 100.

Comment: second =  *((*(stud+1)).points+1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what is failing in your code, but whatever it is, it's because of buffer overflow.

Here

```
_student students[2];
students[2].points[2] = 100;
```

you can't access `students[2]` because it's the third element, and your array has only two, accessing the third element invokes undefined behavior, and of course the same goes for `points`.

In c, an array index starts at `0`, instead of `1`, hence the second element would be

```
_student students[2];
students[1].points[1] = 100;
```

Also don't use that kind of identifier for a type name, it's quite confusing, and generally it's better to make it clear when something is a struct, like in this case.

I would recommend the following

```
struct student {
    int points[2];
};

struct student students[2];
students[1].points[1] = 100;
```

**Edit**: Since the question was edited now the above content seems not logical or incorrect, the actual problem is that this syntax

```
second =  (*(stud+1)).*(points+1);  /* ----> Does not work for sure ! */
```

is invalid, the obvious way is

```
second =  *((*(stud + 1)).points + 1); /* ----> Does work! */
```

or even

```
second =  *((stud + 1)->points + 1); /* ----> Does work! */
```

> I don't understand why `.*(points + 2)` doesn't work. Shouldn't this replace array?

A good question would be, Why do you think it should work?

Comment: I notice now I made a mistake there... but it surprisingly works. I'll change my code in a second.

Comment: @Firmus it's not surprisingly, it's because undefined behavior is undefined. And do you mean that now you will make my answer wrong because that's not the question?

Comment: I'm sorry... but you didn't answer my question in the first place.

Comment: @Firmus Now I did answer your question, despite the fact that your question is not a good one, because it's very hard to understand what you're asking, but it's obvious what you're asking from your code.